# Is there any simple tool for receiving and responding to SOAP messages?

Tags: testing, soap

If I have a server that receives and responds to SOAP messages, I can use SOAPUI as a testing tool to create messages and send them in, and receive and display the response.  But what about the other side of the system?

Let's say I have a server that responds to internal events in its ecosystem and generates SOAP messages.  Is there any tool that can listen for, receive and display these messages, and then allow me to create a response to send back?  As near as I can tell, SOAPUI can't do this.  Are there any similar tools that can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used SOAPUI to mock a web service. That shoul be what you want.

http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html

Comment: From the description on that tutorial series, it looks like this is for creating mock web services to send SOAPUI messages to.  Will this listen for external messages as well?

Comment: I used it locally and configured the client with a local url, so I think it should work for remote calls, too. The setup is not too complicated and you can paste in a static response.